# Cannot set Font Awesome icons from Strings.xml

Tags: android, unicode, font-awesome

Im trying to use Font Awesome icons in my android Application.Ive stored the unicode of various icons i would like to use in strings.xml file but when i run my application i get this [image]

what am i doing wrong?

code

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }

    TextView imgIcon = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lock);
    imgIcon.setTypeface(fontFamily);
    imgIcon.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());
    txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

    // displaying count
    // check whether it set visible or not
    if (navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()) {
        txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
    } else {
        // hide the counter view
        txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Strings.xml

```
<string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
    <item>Home</item>
    <item>Register</item>
    <item>Create Pattern</item>
    <item>Forgot Login Details</item>
    <item>Check Service</item>
    <item>Reset Data</item>
    <item>Settings</item>
</string-array>

<array name="nav_drawer_icons">
    <item>\uf015</item>
    <item>\uf0c7</item>
    <item>\uf00a</item>
    <item>\uf1da</item>
    <item>\uf00c</item>
    <item>\uf021</item>
    <item>\uf013</item>
</array>
```

Constructor to initialize font awesome

```
public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context,
        ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    fontFamily = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/fontawesome.ttf");
}
```

Comment: Where is `fontFamily` defined? Also note that you are assigning to imgIcon the **same value** of txtTitle: `imgIcon.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());
    txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());`

Comment: @funkystein its initialized in the constructor of my list adapter

Comment: Can you show that missing part?

Comment: I'd probably move this `fontFamily = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/fontawesome.ttf");` in the onCreate() or onCreateView() method. And take in account the second part of my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently used android-typeface-textview lib (https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-typeface-textview) to add Fontello (http://fontello.com/) icons to my applications. Download the lib, add the fonts you need to your assets/fonts folder, add

```
xmlns:geekui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to your layout following the instructions of github page, and replace your TextViews on the layout file with similar code to:

```
<com.mobsandgeeks.ui.TypefaceTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    geekui:customTypeface="fonts/YOUR_FONT.ttf" />
```

If you don't like to use 3rd party libs, you will be able to look at the code (it's really simple) to know how to handle typefaces in the correct way.